# Kendo UI TreeView custom attributes

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a Kendo tree that I am binding using local data

Everything works fine with the code I have.

However, I am trying to add custom attributes to the items generated, like `data-name`.

How can I do this using `kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource`?

```
// bind kendo tree
var treeDataSource = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
    data: [{ Id: "id", Text: "Node 1", HasChildren: false, ChildrenFolders: [], HtmlAttributes: { "data-name": "Custom Name" } }],
    schema: {
        model: {
            children: "ChildrenFolders",
            hasChildren: "HasChildren",
            id: "Id",
            htmlAttributes: "HtmlAttributes"
        }
    }
});

this.kendoTreeView = $("#tree").kendoTreeView({
    dataSource: treeDataSource,
    dataTextField: "Text",
    loadOnDemand: false
}).data("kendoTreeView");
```

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to replace the item template in the treeview widget, which unfortunately would mean replacing the whole `_template` method. I'd suggest creating the DOM structure manually (as done [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/web/treeview/overview)), that way you can set the attributes before initializing the treeview.
Another option would be to use the treeview's [template](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/treeview#configuration-template) option (in that case, you can only add the attributes on the child elements though).

Comment: +1 for manually creating the DOM thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

You can get dataSource item properties using dataItem(), method takes jQuery selector as parameter:

```
var treeview = $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                        animation: false,
                        dataSource: dataSource,
                        select: function (e) {
                            var dataitem = treeview.dataItem("#treeview_tv_active");
                            //dataitem.HtmlAttributes
                        }
                    }).data("kendoTreeView");
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please add some lines to explain why this solution works.